# I broke zypper somehow; zypper: /lib64/libresolv.so.2

Tags: opensuse, suse, zypper

Every time I try and run `zypper` I get the following error:

```
WLS1:~ # zypper
zypper: /lib64/libresolv.so.2: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3)

WLS1:~ # dir /lib64/libresolv*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 78608 Jun  6  2008 /lib64/libresolv-2.8.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Sep 13 12:11 /lib64/libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.8.so
```

I am not that familiar with `zypper` and `Suse Enterprise Linux` in general. I know more about Redhat/Centos.

I know that I have `2.8` and that I need `2.9` the question is where can I get `2.9`, I don't know what caused this.

Comment: It looks like you need version 2.9 and you have version 2.8

Comment: Question is what did you do - did you install some rpms directly? Normally anything that is pushed into the SLE update channels has correct dependencies.

Comment: if you install something with yum you can check the history with yum history and track what step you did to downgrade the pkg.

Comment: http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-bugs/2009-01/msg04646.html The main problem seems to be that your libresolv/libkrb5 requires a specifig libc version that it cannot find at runtime. You could try the `ldd` or `nm` commands to investigate the linking symbols of libraries and programs.